# parse.com Query not showing all columns in return

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm building a javascript program that is interacting with the Parse.com API.

I am querying a class named "inventory" in my database as follows:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Inventory");

            query.equalTo("user", $scope.user);
            query.equalTo("product", product);

            query.first({
                success: function(results) {
                    if (results !== undefined) {
                        invId = results.id;
                        invQTY = results.QTY;
                        console.log(results);
                    };
                },
                error: function(object, error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            });
```

The query is finding the correct result.id.  What I am now trying to do is to import an associated column (QTY) with the found row.

[image: parse.com database class screenshot]

I've noticed that the result does not contain this:

```
o {className: "Inventory", _objCount: 18, id: "uvEDwOo823"}
```

This is why my `invQTY = results.QTY;` does not work I guess, but I'm puzzled as to how I would be able to extract this information for the chosen result?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this one out myself.  I needed to change the invQTY to as follows:

```
invQTY = results.get("QTY");
```